# Edge Driver Probleme With Selenium on Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

For my work in my company. I need to test if on the environment I can open a web page from JavaScript with edge. The problem is that this code opens edge but not the google page. it doesn't open anything.

```
const { Builder } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const edge = require("selenium-webdriver/edge");


const edgeDriverPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe";


const driver = new Builder()
  .forBrowser("MicrosoftEdge")
  .setEdgeService(new edge.ServiceBuilder(edgeDriverPath))
  .build();

(async function () {
    try {
      
        await driver.get("https://www.google.com");

        
    } finally {
       
        await driver.quit();
    }
})();
```

In my terminal I get this when i use npm run start:

```
Error: Server terminated early with status 0
    at C:\Users\B63183\Documents\Projet_Automatisation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\remote\index.js:259:24
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v18.15.0
```

After that, the work environment I have is pretty closed with my company. It's possible that it's a problem of version of Edge or selenium.